# Bootstrap NAV way to style color when is collapsed or expanded in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm dealing with bootstrap to style the navbar
Ok, i can style perfectly for desktop or mobile in his initial state.

The problem comes when i try to style on mobile in his expanded and collapsed state.

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/TibicenasDesign/pen/MKNNqa) example, where you can see and example where i can touch the burguer and even the UL.

But, how can i change the logo color and the navbar background color ??
The others were easy because there got class via jQuery.

Hope someone can help me. ( Using CSS & JS ( with or without jQuery ) )

I try this but everything crashed

> ```
> $('.navbar-toggle').toggle(function () {
>   $(".navbar-header").addClass("opened");
>   $("#burguer").addClass("opened");
> }, function () {
>   $(".navbar-header").removeClass("opened");
>   $("#burguer").removeClass("opened");
> });
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Bootstrap events on collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)**:

JS:

```
$('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.navbar').addClass('mobile-opened');
  $('.navbar-brand').addClass('mobile-opened');
});

$('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.navbar').removeClass('mobile-opened');
  $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('mobile-opened');
});
```

CSS:

```
.navbar.mobile-opened {
  background: blue;
}
.navbar-brand.mobile-opened span {
  color: red;
}
```

If you want to change colors when animation is done just use `shown` instead of `show` and `hidden` instead of `hide`

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/ZWzzEp)**

Comment: Worked well, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/ has a lot of useful things.